# Error adding the move graphic functionality to the undomanager

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, undo-redo

The following code is what I am using to get the graphics to be added to the update operation:

```
 //Obtaining the graphic before it is moved
 moveToolbar.on("graphic-move-start", function (evt) {
 //Storing the original geometry in a json string - else it keeps changing
 json1 = JSON.stringify(evt.graphic.geometry);
 });

 //Updating the graphic on move end
 moveToolbar.on("graphic-move-stop", function (evt) {

//Getting the old geometry and converting it back into an object
var obj = JSON.parse(json1);

//Creating the previously created graphic. All the below are needed else the Update operation does not accept it
 oldGraphicMove = new esri.Graphic();
 oldGraphicMove.geometry = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(evt.graphic.geometry));
 oldGraphicMove.symbol = undefined;
 oldGraphicMove.attributes =JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(evt.graphic.attributes));
 oldGraphicMove._count = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(evt.graphic._count));
 oldGraphicMove._extent = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(evt.graphic._extent));
 oldGraphicMove._graphicsLayer = evt.graphic._graphicsLayer;
 oldGraphicMove._layer = evt.graphic._layer;
 oldGraphicMove._offsets = evt.graphic._offsets;
 oldGraphicMove._shape = evt.graphic._shape;

 //Changing the value of the oldGraphicMove object to the values of the graphic before it was moved
 for (var z = 0; z < obj.rings[0].length; z++)
 {
  oldGraphicMove.geometry.rings[0][z] = obj.rings[0][z];
 }
 newGraphicMove = evt.graphic;

 //Creating the operation to add to the undomanager
  var operation = new Update({
        featureLayer: evt.graphic._graphicsLayer, //The layer that will contain the modified graphic
        preUpdatedGraphics: [oldGraphicMove], //The graphic before the changes are created
        postUpdatedGraphics: [newGraphicMove] //The graphic after the changes are made
       });

 //Adding the undo/redo operation
undoManager.add(operation);

 json1 = {};
 json2 = {};

 //Updating the graphic

 evt.graphic._graphicsLayer.applyEdits(null, [evt.graphic], null);
});
```

However on the part of var operation = new update the following error is thrown:

```
Uncaught TypeError: a.preUpdatedGraphics[b].geometry.toJson is not a function
at Object.constructor (Update.js:4)
at new <anonymous> (init.js:108)
at Object.<anonymous> (eGISEditing.js:1141)
at Object.<anonymous> (init.js:1191)
at Object.h [as onGraphicMoveStop] (init.js:244)
at Object._moveStopHandler (_GraphicMover.js:9)
at Object.<anonymous> (init.js:177)
at Object.h [as onMoveStop] (init.js:244)
at Object.destroy (Mover.js:3)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (init.js:177)
```

I have been through both passed graphics and all geometry is present within them, and as a result I am unable to determine how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find a solution after weeks of experimenting, hopefully this will help someone else.

This first part of the code stored the original graphic

```
//Obtaining the graphic before it is moved
moveToolbar.on("graphic-move-start", function (evt) {
//Storing the original geometry in a json string - else it keeps changing
json1 = JSON.stringify(evt.graphic.geometry);
});
```

This consists of the new graphic and the process to add to the undo manager

```
//Updating the graphic on move end
moveToolbar.on("graphic-move-stop", function (evt) {

//Getting the old geometry and converting it back into an object
 var obj = JSON.parse(json1);

//Creating the previously created graphic. All the below are needed else the Update operation does not accept it
//Basically you are taking the individual attributes from the json string and applying them to the oldgraphicMove object in order to create a new identical graphic

oldGraphicMove = new esri.Graphic();
oldGraphicMove.geometry = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(evt.graphic.geometry));
oldGraphicMove.symbol = undefined;
oldGraphicMove.attributes=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(evt.graphic.attributes));                                    
oldGraphicMove._count = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(evt.graphic._count));                                 
oldGraphicMove._extent = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(evt.graphic._extent));                            
oldGraphicMove._graphicsLayer = evt.graphic._graphicsLayer;
oldGraphicMove._layer = evt.graphic._layer;
oldGraphicMove._offsets = evt.graphic._offsets;
oldGraphicMove._shape = evt.graphic._shape;

if (obj.rings != undefined) {
//Changing the value of the oldGraphicMove object to the values of the graphic before it was moved
for (var z = 0; z < obj.rings[0].length; z++) {

oldGraphicMove.geometry.rings[0][z] = obj.rings[0][z];
}
}
else
if (obj.paths != undefined)
{
 //Changing the value of the oldGraphicMove object to the values of the graphic before it was moved
for (var z = 0; z < obj.paths[0].length; z++) {

  oldGraphicMove.geometry.paths[0][z] = obj.paths[0][z];
  }
  }                                                     
oldGraphicMove.geometry.__proto__ = evt.graphic.geometry.__proto__;

oldGraphicMove.geometry.spatialReference = 
evt.graphic.geometry.spatialReference;

newGraphicMove = evt.graphic;

 //Creating the operation to add to the undomanager
var operation = new Update({
featureLayer: evt.graphic._graphicsLayer, //The layer that will contain the modified graphic
preUpdatedGraphics: [oldGraphicMove], //The graphic before the changes are created
postUpdatedGraphics: [newGraphicMove] //The graphic after the changes are made
});

//Adding the undo/redo operation
undoManager.add(operation);

json1 = {};
json2 = {};

//Updating the graphic

evt.graphic._graphicsLayer.applyEdits(null, [evt.graphic], null);
});
```